# Steganography using video and audio stream in java or C++

Tags: java, visual-c++

I need to load the video and modify it. How can I read bit by bit the stream and change it for purposes of Steganography. I was not able to find any example of showing video file in bits. Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Video Steganography](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9567818/video-steganography)

Answer (score 0):

First you have to get what is a video. Between the data on disk (or received from the net) and the final pixels of the frame shown into a window (the actual image of a single frame), there's an algorithm (unless your video is just a "sequence" of uncompressed pictures). Once you are able to put yourself in the middle (reading decoded data), you can alter the data. But then, you've to put them back in the original format, that is often if not always a compressed data with a lossy complicated algorithm that easily will destroy your "injected" hidden bits, unless you are so clever to avoid that choosing the way you elaborate the stream carefully.

The same problem exists for hiding data into a jpeg image (known methods use the coefficients of the DCT, which are stored someway into the final jpeg file format). Googling you can find links like [this](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.178.7157&rep=rep1&type=pdf), which I've not checked but the idea as said is known and you can find resources on it.

Hiding data into a video maybe is not so different, but it is not, as you can see, as direct as injecting it into a uncompressed or losslessly compressed image / text / sound / whatever.

Back to being able to "see" video as "bits": once you load a video file, once you decode it, maybe frame by frame (use a library...), you obtain bytes; extracting and modifying bits is a matter of cool operations like shift and bitwise-and/or/eor. To have an idea of what it could mean to decode a video file, you can search for source code of players (e.g. mplayer) and codec it can use (if you want to have details, but indeed you're interested just in using a codec the way the player would do).